# Odoo 12 Create button on Tree View on stock.quant

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo, odoo-12

Is there any way to create a button on `stock.quant` model?

All solution i found is related to `Create/Import` Buttons, BUT on `stock.quant` model doesn't have them.

My code so far:

Path: `locations_quants_report/views/templates.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
      <data>
            <template id="assets_backend" name="stock_quant_tree_view_button" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
                  <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="/tree_menu/static/src/js/tree_view_button.js"></script>
                  </xpath>
            </template>
      </data>
</odoo>
```

Path: `locations_quants_report/static/src/xml/tree_view_button.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <template id="template" xml:space="preserve">
          <t t-extend="ListView.buttons">
            <t t-jquery="button.o_list_button_add" t-operation="after">
                  <button t-if="widget.model == 'stock.quant'" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Print</button>
            </t>
          </t>
      </template>
```

Also declare them on `__manifest__.py`

```
    'data': [
        ...
        'views/template.xml'
    ],
    'qweb': [
        'static/src/xml/tree_view_button.xml',
    ],
```

Any solution i whould be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of button you want to add and what is the purpose of the button?

Comment: i want to print the data from `stock.quant` model i manage to create the button on `stock.quant` and call the wizzard i made but for some reason the button showing in all views. if you intresting i can update the post. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this is not the way to add the Print button. You can check the sale order report to add the print button at the top before the action button.

Comment: i found solution to my problem thanks for the effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution to call the wizard i made for printing the lines.

Path: `locations_quants_report/views/templates.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <template id="assets_backend"  name="stock_quant_tree_view_button" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
            <xpath expr="." position="inside">
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/locations_quants_report/static/src/js/tree_view_button.js"></script>
            </xpath>
        </template>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Path: `locations_quants_report/static/src/xml/tree_view_button.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <template id="template" xml:space="preserve">
          <t t-extend="ListView.buttons">
            <t t-jquery="button.o_list_button_save" t-operation="before">
                <t t-if="widget.modelName == 'stock.quant'">
                  <button id="custom_print_btn" class="btn btn-primary o_list_button_custom_print" type="button" >Print</button> 
                </t>
            </t>
          </t>
      </template>
```

Path: `locations_quants_report/static/src/js/tree_view_button.js`

```
odoo.define('locations_quants_report.tree_view_button', function (require){
    "use strict";       
    var core = require('web.core');
    var ListView = require('web.ListView'); 
    var ListController = require("web.ListController");

    var includeDict = {
        renderButtons: function () {
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);
            if (this.modelName == 'stock.quant') {
                var your_btn = this.$buttons.find('button.o_list_button_custom_print');
                your_btn.on('click', this.proxy('o_list_button_custom_print'));
            }
        },
        o_list_button_custom_print: function(){
            this.do_action({
                name: "Open a wizard",
                type: 'ir.actions.act_window',
                res_model: 'locations.quants.report',
                view_mode: 'form',
                view_type: 'form',
                views: [[false, 'form']],
                target: 'new',
            });
        }
    };

    ListController.include(includeDict);
});
```

Also declare them on `__manifest__.py`

```
    'data': [
        ...
        'views/template.xml'
    ],
    'qweb': [
        'static/src/xml/tree_view_button.xml',
    ],
```